How can I resize the persistent logging-partition for another one on my live USB stick?
I have made a live USB stick for Xubuntu 22.04 LTS. I used a 64GB Intenso  Ultra Line version 8.01. After I have created the stick, lsblk shows me three partitions on it:
NAME    SIZE PTTYPE PHY-SEC LOG-SEC PARTFLAGS                            VENDOR   MODEL       REV
sdb    58,6G gpt        512     512                                      Intenso  Ultra Line 8.01
├─sdb1  3,8G gpt        512     512 0x1000000000000001
├─sdb2    5M gpt        512     512
└─sdb3  300K gpt        512     512 0x1000000000000001

and
NAME    SIZE FSUSE% FSTYPE  LABEL                   UUID
sdb    58,6G        iso9660 Xubuntu 24.04 LTS amd64 2024-04-24-20-17-44-00
├─sdb1  3,8G        iso9660 Xubuntu 24.04 LTS amd64 2024-04-24-20-17-44-00
├─sdb2    5M        vfat    ESP                     37B6-BC6E
└─sdb3  300K

gdisk tells me about it:
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdb: 122880000 sectors, 58.6 GiB
Model: Ultra Line
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 68F11F7C-9460-4739-8F79-899A4819EEA1
Partition table holds up to 248 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 63
First usable sector is 64, last usable sector is 7949112
Partitions will be aligned on 4-sector boundaries
Total free space is 1 sectors (512 bytes)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              64         7938371   3.8 GiB     0700  ISO9660
   2         7938372         7948511   5.0 MiB     EF00  Appended2
   3         7948512         7949111   300.0 KiB   0700  Gap1

So there should be lots of empty space on it, only 3,8 GiB are used.
After the first use of it, a 54,8GiB partition writable fills all the empty space:
NAME     SIZE FSUSE% FSTYPE   LABEL                   UUID
sdb     58,6G        iso9660  Xubuntu 24.04 LTS amd64 2024-04-24-20-17-44-00
├─sdb1   3,8G        iso9660  Xubuntu 24.04 LTS amd64 2024-04-24-20-17-44-00
├─sdb2     5M        vfat     ESP                     37B6-BC6E
├─sdb3   300K
└─sdb4  54,8G        ext4     writable                00473fa5-45e9-466c-b2c0-dab19f0ad4b5

This partition is owned by root:root and it accumulates directories with log files about each use process (ca 4,4MiB per boot process).
Does anybody know how to make use of them?
I would like to resize this partition to some more reasonable size and add another one into the empty space after making it smaller. But GPartEd shows the whole stick as one monolithic entity!
How can I add another ext4-partition for general use (e.g. scripts and files to be used after installation), onto this stick?

I suggest that you create a persistent live Xubuntu system, that uses the whole drive. You can use mkusb for that purpose. There are several alternatives,

via dus (mkusb-dus):

dus-persistent - well polished, but may have problems with new computers in UEFI mode with secure boot
dus-iso2usb - should work well with most computers (leaves some drive space unallocated, which should reduce problems with 'choking' the internal system of the USB drive)


via mkusb-plug - should work well with most computers


It is possible to boot the persistent live drives by dus also in normal live mode (without persistence), which you would select for example when installing Xubuntu into an internal drive.

Edit:
It is possible to edit the partition table with the command line tool fdisk, even with a cloned drive containing an iso9660 file system. This means that you can shrink the partition labeled 'writable' and use the unallocated space created by that operation for another partition.
Please notice that you must do those operations in a coordinated way with corresponding operations to shrink and create file systems, so it is rather complicated. For that reason I suggested other methods in this answer (and with details in comments).

@Adalbert Hanßen Why are you asking a question in the comment field of an answer to someone else question? If you have a question you need to make a new question.

@AdalbertHanßen, You can :-) Make a persistent live drive and change the label of the partition for persistence (to something else than 'writable' or 'casper-rw') and you will get a live only system with a partition that can be used for storage. Another alternative is to modify the 'linux line' in grub.cfg (remove the boot option 'persistent').

An alternative is to change the boot option 'persistent' to 'nopersistent'. Then you need not even change the label of the ext4 partition. It is easier to modify grub.cfg in systems made by dus (dus-persistent or dus-iso2usb) because of the read-write file system, while a cloned system has a read-only iso9660 file system).

@sudosus: Thanks for your comments. The part of my question "How can I add another ext4-partition for general use" still lacks an answer. GPartEd shows the whole stick as one monolithic entity and I can't resize the persistent partition writable apparently used for the log files in order to create another one aside of it.

If you want to keep the partition labeled 'writable', but shrink it and then create a new partition, you can do it with gparted, if you start with a persistent live drive created by mkusb-dus. But it is also possible with the command line tool fdisk, even with a cloned drive containing an iso9660 file system. This is what I do (for debian systems) in the tool mkusb-plug, so I know that it works. I did not recommend it because I think it is more difficult than what I already suggested.
